# Kurento : Not getting video

Tags: webrtc, kurento

I am implementing a android client for kurento One2One call.

I am using ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

Installed kurento 6.6.1

And downloded kurento-tutorial-java.

When i access the one2one call from browser, I get connecting and getting local and remote tream. But If I connect from browser in a tab, and android client running in my laptop, am not getting the remote video.

I implemented all steps of kurento-one2one-client.

Below is the screenshot of candidated connection in the ubuntu.

My prime suspect, am not able to get video, since the candidates are listening with internal ip?
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a STUN and TURN server urls in the following [file](http://doc-kurento.readthedocs.io/en/stable/installation_guide.html#stun-and-turn-servers) on your KMS.

Also you can try adding the same configuration in the mediaConstraints from the client side.

```
var iceServers = [
   {"urls":"turn:**.**.***.**:3478","username":"<username>","credential":"<credential>"},
   {"urls":"stun:stunserver.org:19302"}
];
```

Something similar can be found in this [link](https://www.avaya.com/blogs/archives/2014/08/understanding-webrtc-media-connections-ice-stun-and-turn.html)